# Why TreeView control creating blank node?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Frist see following code and images.

Code A

```
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node A");
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node B");
```

Output :
[image]

Code B

```
        TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
        tn.Nodes.Add("Node A");
        tn.Nodes.Add("Node B");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

[image]

Now my problem is that `treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);` creating a blank node, but my requirement is like `Code A's` image type (without blank node). If you need any other information please let me know.

**UPDATE**
Actually Ithere is a function in my code which returns a `TreeNode` and I have to add this node to `TreeView` control without first blank level.

Comment: If you have a function that returns a tree node, and you want to add it to the root of your TreeView, just write treeView1.Nodes.Add(yourReturnedTreeNode);

Comment: @Moozhe: That doesn't sound quite right.  I suspect he wants to add the children of the returned node without adding the returned node itself.  If so, my modified answer will help.

Comment: One can only make wild guesses as to what he actually wants to do, I took "there is a function in my code which returns a TreeNode and I have to add this node to TreeView control" at face value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
```

creates an actual item.  You didn't give it any text, so it appears blank.  Then next two lines are adding child nodes to the blank node.

If your goal is the code in "A", why are you writing "B"?

**Edit**: response to your updated question

You have a function returning a root blank tree node, which contains children you want.  So, something like this is in order.

```
foreach (var node in returnedNode.Nodes)
{
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
}
```

OR

```
treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(returnedNode.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToArray());
```

Comment: can we remove level 0 of `TreeView` so that treenode(return by function) just appear at level 0?

Comment: @Jams:  Either I don't understand your question, or that is already happening in the edited section of my code.  (Just make sure treeView1 is empty before adding the returnedNode's nodes.)

Comment: You understand question well and your edit answer doing well, but I am also trying to find other approch, if not possible then your answer is here to solve problem.

Comment: @jams: is the additional option more the style you were looking for?

Comment: `treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(returnedNode.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToArray());
` this is the exact solution for me thanks for your patience effords.

Answer (score 2):

```
TreeNode t1 = new TreeNode( "Node A" );         
treeView1.Nodes.Add( t1 );
TreeNode t2 = new TreeNode( "Node B" );         
treeView1.Nodes.Add( t2 );
```

You have to add nodes directly UNDER `treeView1`, not under it's child as in 2nd snippet.

Comment: can we achive same functionality by using `TreeNode tn = new TreeNode()` default constructor?

Comment: Yes, we can. TreeNode t1 = new TreeNode(); t1.Text = "Node A"; treeView1.Nodes.Add( t1 );

Answer (score 2):

Name of the root node is empty because you've used [default constructor of the TreeNode class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8h64c9.aspx).

Try out specifying name for the `tn` node using [TreeNode(string text) constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytx906df.aspx)

```
    // specify name of the root node
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode("Root Node Name");
    tn.Nodes.Add("Node A");
    tn.Nodes.Add("Node B");
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

**UPDATE**: Since question was updated

Just set `Text` property for node returned by a function:

```
TreeNode treeNode = YourMethodWhichCreatesTreeNode();
treeNode.Text = "Root Node Name";
treeView.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```